# Any difference between "ashamed of something" and "ashamed of self for something"?

Tags: phrases, differences

So I did a quick drawing and I was trying to decide what to say to my friends in regards to how I felt about it, and this idea came up. I could either say, "I'm proud, yet ashamed of myself for doing the drawing," or say "I'm proud, yet ashamed of the drawing." Is there any difference between these two statements? And if so, which is better to use?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Ashamed of yourself" would indicate that you are embarrassed that you found the motivation to think the subject matter was suitable for a drawing.

"Ashamed of the drawing" would indicate you feel the drawing is of poor quality.

The use of the word "proud" in the example is contradictory to using the word ashamed and should have more explanation of what specifically you are proud of, as in *I'm proud of the way the drawing turned out, but ashamed of myself for finding the boss's broken leg funny.*

Or *I'm proud of the concept behind the drawing, but ashamed that my artistic skills are so poor.*

Comment: Okay, I get it now. Thanks for the examples, especially. And yes, of course I knew the word "proud" was contradictory, ha, and the way the example sentence puts it would sound better in this case than just saying "proud, yet ashamed." This will definitely be useful in the future.

Answer (score 0):

> ashamed of myself

describes a person as shameful.  It is therefore a moral or a psychological judgment, but not an aesthetic evaluation. It is also (intensely) personal.

> ashamed of the drawing

This judgment could be moral, aesthetic, political.  Because it is a verdict on an object, it allows others to comment on it without insulting you.